# Weird tab error, can't put my finger on where I went wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make use of a while loop to iterate through a list of three variables that's are also assigned to three queues implemented through linked lists. I called this list full. My while loop is supposed to keep running while my list of full queues is still at 3.

Here's the chunk of code. I get the tab error after the pop function.

```
while len(full) == 3:
x = random.random()
if 0 <= x <.33:
    if full[0].isEmpty() == True:
        full.pop(0)
    else:
    Runway.enqueue(airplane)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have at least one tab character in your code at the start of your `else:` line. (There are two tabs in this editor--there may be only one in your code.) The other lines use spaces.

In Python it is a *very good idea* to use only spaces in your code and *never use tabs*. It is possible to use some tabs and get away with it, but getting away with it is very unlikely. Set your code editor to insert spaces when you press the Tab key--all good editors have a setting for that.

In the code you show us, the line after the `else:` is not indented at all, so that should also give you an error. Indent that line by four spaces, after you replace the tabs with spaces in the `else:` line.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a tab error because you're mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation. 
I copy pasted your code and the "else" line starts with a tab instead of 4 spaces. Try changing it to 4 spaces and see if the problem is fixed.